Facebook Unable to Post Video
For the past few days, I have been unable to post a video on Facebook.
This includes making a post with a video and making a comment with a video with my personal account or a page.
When i'm in my personal account and try to comment with a video on the post, the request is returning
{"debug_info":{"retriable":false,"type":"NotAuthorizedError","message":"User not authorized to perform this request"}}

Basically the request keeps uploading over and over repeatably, goes to 100% uploaded, but then starts over and repeats returning that message every few seconds.
I have shared videos on my pages for along time and cannot share them anymore.
Is anybody else having this problem? How can I fix this or go about getting it fixed? It's almost been a week, I share 1 video on my page every day.
I'm literally using the chrome browser.
